# How to save an int on exit?

Tags: java, android, admob

I'm rather new to both Java and Android development.  I'm using one of the Android Studio's Google AdMod ad activity templates and I want to be able to save the level integer when the app closes and recall it when it starts back up again. I've found many examples using `SharedPreferences` but I don't know how to use it in this project. It's probably simple.

Here is my code:

```
package com.example.dthom.adsimulator;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
// Remove the below line after defining your own ad unit ID.
private static final String TOAST_TEXT = "Test ads are being shown. "
        + "To show live ads, replace the ad unit ID in 
res/values/strings.xml with your own ad unit ID.";

private static final int START_LEVEL = 1;
private int mLevel;
private Button mNextLevelButton;
private InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;
private TextView mLevelTextView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Create the next level button, which tries to show an interstitial 
when clicked.
    mNextLevelButton = ((Button) findViewById(R.id.next_level_button));
    mNextLevelButton.setEnabled(false);
    mNextLevelButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            showInterstitial();
        }
    });

    // Create the text view to show the level number.
    mLevelTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.level);
    mLevel = START_LEVEL;

    // Create the InterstitialAd and set the adUnitId (defined in 
values/strings.xml).
    mInterstitialAd = newInterstitialAd();
    loadInterstitial();

    // Toasts the test ad message on the screen. Remove this after defining 
your own ad unit ID.
    Toast.makeText(this, TOAST_TEXT, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

private InterstitialAd newInterstitialAd() {
    InterstitialAd interstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
    interstitialAd.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.interstitial_ad_unit_id));
    interstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded() {
            mNextLevelButton.setEnabled(true);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
            mNextLevelButton.setEnabled(true);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdClosed() {
            // Proceed to the next level.
            goToNextLevel();
        }
    });
    return interstitialAd;
}

private void showInterstitial() {
    // Show the ad if it's ready. Otherwise toast and reload the ad.
    if (mInterstitialAd != null && mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
        mInterstitialAd.show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Ad did not load", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        goToNextLevel();
    }
}

private void loadInterstitial() {
    // Disable the next level button and load the ad.
    mNextLevelButton.setEnabled(false);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .setRequestAgent("android_studio:ad_template").build();
    mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
}

private void goToNextLevel() {
    // Show the next level and reload the ad to prepare for the level after.
    mLevelTextView.setText("Level " + (++mLevel));
    mInterstitialAd = newInterstitialAd();
    loadInterstitial();
}
}
```

any help is welcome

Comment: According to android documentation it says you should release resources and other shutdown operations in the onStop method i.e.
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    // call the superclass method first
    super.onStop();
//Your state savePreferencesMethod here
}

more details check onStop method here.
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html

and using sharedPrefrences here:

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html

Comment: GET:
Context context = getActivity();
SharedPreferences sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences("preferenceKeyNameHere", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
------------------------------

PUT:
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.putInt("preferenceKeyNameHere", yourNumber);
editor.commit();

the key that you use to store the item, use that for retrieving the item

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you want to get an instance of SharedPreferences:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
```

Now you can read a number. 1 will be the default number incase you have never before saved anything. level will be the name of that Integer:

```
Integer level = sharedPref.getInt("level",1);
```

Too save it, you need to get an instance of the editor and then put in the new level. Afterwards you need to use either commit() or apply(). Commit() will ensure the level is saved before your program executes the next command, while apply will save in background. We again need an instance of sharedPreferences. You can make a new one or use the old one.

```
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
    editor.putInt("level",newlevel);
    editor.commit();
```

If you want to set the level when the user exits do it in onStop() and then read it again when you need it:

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
    editor.putInt("level",newlevel);
    editor.commit();
    super.onStop();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can use `SharedPreferences`.

1. Get an instance of `SharedPreferences`:

   ```
   SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("preferences", MODE_PRIVATE);
   ```
2. Save the `int`:

   ```
   preferences.edit().putInt("level", value).commit();
   ```
3. Retrieve the `int` (you can replace the `0` with the default level):

   ```
   preferences.getInt("level", 0);
   ```